# Array: Changing to "+" to "," inside an array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have some code as example in below:

```
var andThingys = $('.AndsovKeywordArr').eq(i).text();
andThingys.replace(/\+/g,',');

var res1 = andThingys.split(",");
console.log(res1);
```

it returns something like `"andKeywords":["bsadbd+sbdsbsdb","nfdndf+nfdndfnnfd"]`

but i want to change all the "+" to "," for those array elements,

how may i do that?

The result i'd like to see, looks like below:

```
`"andKeywords":["bsadbd,sbdsbsdb","nfdndf,nfdndfnnfd"]`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using the result of the `replace()` method. Just set the result back to `andThingys`:

```
andThingys = andThingys.replace(/\+/g, ',');
```

> i want to use the split method to convert it to array first and covert the rest of "+" into ","

In this case your logic is flawed. You need to `split()` first, then loop through the resulting array values replacing the `+` as you go, like this:

```js
var i = 0;
var res1 = $('.AndsovKeywordArr').eq(i).text().split(',').map(function(v) {
  return v.replace(/\+/g, ',');
});

console.log(res1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="AndsovKeywordArr">bsadbd+sbdsbsdb,nfdndf+nfdndfnnfd</div>
```

Comment: i want to use the split method to convert it to array first and covert the rest of "+" into ","

Comment: no this is not the result i wanted

Comment: In which case you should have given a clearer example of your expected output in the question. I have updated the answer for you